# Obtener index de Foreach en C#

Tags: c#

Normalmente hago iteraciones utilizando la sentencia de control `for` y así obtengo el index de la iteración fácilmente, pero la duda que tengo es la siguiente, ¿Hay alguna manera de sacar el index de la iteracion en un `foreach` en `c#`?

ya que normalmente lo saco de la siguiente manera:

```
int i=0;
foreach (var item in array)
{

   i++;
}
```

La otra preguntaria sería, sí hay manera de sacar el index de un manera diferente a la del ejemplo ¿Cual es ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Creo que la forma adecuada de obtener el index en un `foreach` es la que estás usando porque es un código sencillo y óptimo y hay veces que puede ser interesante usarlo.

Un ejemplo de ello es con la clase [ConcurrentBag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
ConcurrentBag<int> cb = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
cb.Add(1);
cb.Add(2);
cb.Add(3);

int loop = 0;
foreach(int n in cb)
{
    loop++;
    Console.WriteLine("Loop: {0} | Number: {0}", loop, n);
}
```

En este caso no tiene sentido usar la secuencia `for` porque, entre otras cosas, se podrían añadir/eliminar elementos desde otro hilo de ejecución mientras se recorre la lista

Por último, lo que **nunca debería hacer es usar `Array.IndexOf`** para obtener el índice porque se va a forzar una búsqueda en la lista por cada iteración

```
string[] array = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
foreach (var item in array)
{
    // Aquí se hará una búsqueda en la lista perdiendo rendimiento
    var index = Array.IndexOf(array, item);
    Console.WriteLine($"{index} - {item}");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> La otra preguntaria sería, sí hay manera de sacar el index de un manera diferente a la del ejemplo

Si estás recorriendo los elementos para crear una nueva lista con estos, puedes usar el método de extensión `Select` ([documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/bb534869%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)) el cual tiene una sobrecarga con el índice.

```
var numeros = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var cuadrados = numeros.Select((n, i) => new { Valor = n * n, Indice = i + 1 });
```

Answer (score 2):

A modo de adición a lo que todos los demás han escrito, quiero escribir un poco de teoría.

`for`: Es un ciclo que itera dentro de **<s>todo</s>** un conjunto de elementos, ya sea una lista, o un `Array` *(Ejemplo genérico)*:

```
int[] Array = { 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length; i++)
    Console.Write(Array[i] + ", ");
```

En cada una de sus iteraciones va a dar con el valor del elemento `i` en el `Array`, provocando el siguiente resultado:

```
5, 4, 3, 2, 1,
```

Como se puede apreciar, sí, efectivamente se accede a cada elemento dentro del `Array`.

Con `foreach` esto podría ser traducido a:

```
foreach (int e in Array)
    Console.Write(e + ", ");
```

El cual produciría la misma salida, ahora bien, estamos hablando de `Array`, un array solo es un conjunto de elementos finitos, si nos orientamos a un `List<T>`, las cosas cambian:

En una clase cuya dependencia principal es un iterador, ¿Por qué no usar `foreach` para acceder a **cada** elemento del `List<T>`? Si hacemos mención del rendimiento, estamos en nada, la clase `List` esta preparada para *"fuego"* en el .NET Framework y el ciclo `foreach` tambien, sino, prueben ustedes la velocidad en cada uno. *(Otro ejemplo genérico)*:

```
public static void Main()
{
    List<int> Lista = new List<int>();
    Stopwatch S = new Stopwatch();

    Console.WriteLine("Iniciando cronometro para llenar la lista con 10,000 valores");
    S.Start();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) Lista.Add(i);
    S.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("Tiempo pasado llenar la lista: " + S.Elapsed.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("\n\nIniciando cronometro para acceder a cada elemento usando el ciclo for:");
    S.Restart();
    for (int i = 0; i < Lista.Count; i++)
        Console.Write(Lista[i]);
    S.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("\nTiempo transcurrido usando for: " + S.Elapsed.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine("\nIniciando cronometro para acceder a cada elemento usando foreach: ");
    S.Restart();
    foreach (int e in Lista)
        Console.Write(e);
    S.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("\nTiempo transcurrido usando foreach: " + S.Elapsed.ToString());
}
```

*(Correr el ejemplo anterior varias veces para comprobar los resultados obtenidos)*

Ahora bien, si lo que se desea es obtener el indice de un elemento en una clase que contiene iteradores o soporta `index`, lo más recomendable es hacer uso de su indizador o llamar a su respectiva función `IndexOf` (Como hacen mención [Asier Villanueva](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9465/4499) y [rsciriano](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/9704/4499))

`IndexOf`: Es una función que devuelve un entero con la posición actual de un elemento en tu lista, cabe mencionar que esta función solo está disponible para las colecciones que estan en el espacio de nombres `System.Collections.Generic`, su aspecto es más o menos así:

```
int IndexOf<T>(this T[] item, T toSearch)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
        if (item[i] == toSearch) return i;
    return -1; // No recuerdo si arroja al no encontrarlo, por lo que devolvemos null.
}
```

Que es prácticamente lo mismo que iterar tu mismo la lista o colección para obtener el indice del elemento actual, los usos prácticos de esta función, vienen cuando necesitas sacar un elemento especifico, ejemplo *genérico*:

```
IList<string> Nombres = new List<string>() {
    "NaCl", "Miquel", "Asier", "Op", "Etc.."
};
```

Y necesito sacar especificamente mi nombre, si este existe:

```
int IndexDeOp = Nombres.IndexOf("Op");
```

El valor de `IndexDeOp` es `3`, por lo que si no necesitas iterar dentro de la lista, esta es tu mejor opción.

Como útima mención, el ciclo `foreach` **<s>sólo puede ser utilizado</s>** se utiliza en clases o "colecciones" que implementen `IEnumerable[<T>]`, pero esto no es del todo necesario, basta con que se implementen las siguientes funciones y propiedades: `GetEnumerator`, `Current` y `MoveNext`.

Aquí dejo algunos enlaces de referencia:

`for`, `foreach`, [un fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aKQOkS).

Comment: Solo como curiosidad, para usar `foreach` no es estrictamente necesario que la clase implemente la interfaz `IEnumerable`.  Es suficiente con que tenga un método llamado `GetEnumerator` el cual devuelva un objeto que implemente una propiedad `Current` y un método `MoveNext`.  Como en este ejemplo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/y5lUI4.  No es que recomiende hacerlo pero es interesante saberlo.

Comment: @Equiso Buen dato, voy a editar la respuesta.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes obtener el índice a través del método IndexOf de la clase Array:

```
        string[] array = {"Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"};
        foreach (var item in array)
        {
            var index = Array.IndexOf(array, item);
            Console.WriteLine($"{index} - {item}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Pero lo más lógico es que si necesitas el índice utilices un for.

Comment: Al usar `Array.IndexOf`se va a realizar una búsqueda en la lista por lo que va a afectar al rendimiento. La opción de ir incrementando un contador es mas adecuada

Answer (score 0):

Yo usaría otro tipo de bucle, puesto que con Foreach, necesitas añadir un contador. Puedes igual usar Foreach y un contador a parte.

*Yo usaría un bucle while*

```
int i=-1;

while(++i<array.Length)
  {
  // código del bucle..
  }
```

Comment: FYI, `Internamente Foreach ha de usar por necesidad, de algún modo, un contador que no se maneja desde el código`, foreach usa iteradores, que tienen los metodos Current y MoveNext, ninguno de los cuales necesita utilizar un contandor.

Answer (score -1):

Lo correcto seria usando un for así:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    //i te dará el indice automáticamente.
    Console.WriteLine(i); 
}
```

Answer (score -4):

El Blucle `foreach` es utilizado en iteraciones en las que no es necesario obtener o trabajar con el índice sino con los objetos, para trabajar con el índice utiliza el bucle `for`

Comment: El op dice que lo hace comúnmente de esta manera, está preguntando si hay otra forma de sacarlo.