# foreach con clases que no 'implementan' IEnumerable/IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net

Ví el comentario de [Equiso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/9463/obtener-index-de-foreach-en-c/17166?noredirect=1#comment28178_17166) en una de mis respuestas con un detalle interesante y es que implementó una interfaz *(O parte de ella)* sin usar el operador `:` a la derecha del nombre del objeto.

Proporcionó el siguiente código:

```
public class TestEnumerator
{
    private int _veces;
    public TestEnumerator(int veces) { _veces = veces; }
    public object Current  { get { return "Hola " + _veces; } }
    public bool MoveNext() { return _veces-- > 0; }
}

public class Test
{
    public TestEnumerator GetEnumerator() { return new TestEnumerator(10); }
}

public static void Main()
{
    var test = new Test();

    foreach (var x in test)
        Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Efectivamente la salida es la esperada:

```
Hola 9
Hola 8
Hola 7
Hola 6
Hola 5
Hola 4
Hola 3
Hola 2
Hola 1
Hola 0
```

Lo que es equivalente a la implementación de una `IEnumerable<T>` e `IEnumerator` en sus respectivas clases. ¿Cómo es llamado este tipo de implementación? Dado que es una clase con un enumerador, pero no es una colección, diría que es una implementación a medias de `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo con [`foreach, in` (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6(VS.71).aspx):

> Una expresión con una colección o arreglo. El tipo de elemento de la colección debe ser convertible al tipo del  *identificador*. No usar una expresión que se evalúa a **null**.
>   Evalúa a un tipo que implementa **IEnumerable** o un tipo que declara un método **GetEnumerator**. En el último caso, debe regresar ya sea un tipo que implementa **IEnumerator** o que declara todos los métodos definidos en **IEnumerator**.

El código que has mencionado cumple con el último caso. El método [`Reset()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.reset(v=vs.110).aspx) no *necesita* implementarse *necesariamente*.

De hecho, una sentencia `foreach` de la forma:<sup>1</sup>

```
foreach (V v in x) embedded-statement
```

es entonces expandida a:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
       V v;
       while (e.MoveNext()) {
           v = (V)(T)e.Current;
           embedded-statement
       }
    }
    finally {
       ... // Dispose of e
    }
}
```

La variable `e` no es visible o accesible desde el código original. La variable `v` es de sólo lectura en la sentencia embebida (*embedded-statement*).

---

*Notas*

1. Véase *The C# Programming Language (Covering C# 4.0)* de Anders Hejlsberg, Mads Torgersen, Scott Wiltamuth, Peter Golde, pág. 519.

Answer (score 2):

Aqui

[Iteradores (C# y Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/dscyy5s0.aspx)

se menciona

> Al crear un iterador para una clase o struct, no se tiene que implementar la interfaz IEnumerator completa.  Cuando el compilador detecta el iterador, genera automáticamente los métodos Current, MoveNext, y Dispose de la interfaz IEnumerator o IEnumerator.

Entiendo que el `foreach` esta haciendo uso de `Current`, `MoveNext()` y `GetEnumerator()` pero con esto le alcanza, no valida que este la interfaz `IEnumerable` y `IEnumerator` esten declaradas, ya que estas igual exponen la funcionalidad que la iteraccion necesita

[How to make a Visual C# class usable in a foreach statement](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322022)

Lo correcto seria definir las interfaces que aseguran que la clase sea iterable

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();

        foreach (var x in test)
            Console.WriteLine(x);

    }
}

public class TestEnumerator : IEnumerator 
{
    private int _veces;
    public TestEnumerator(int veces) { _veces = veces; }
    public object Current  { get { return "Hola " + _veces; } }
    public bool MoveNext() { return _veces-- > 0; }

    public void Reset(){ _veces = 0; }
}

public class Test : IEnumerable
{
    public IEnumerator GetEnumerator() { 
        return (IEnumerator)new TestEnumerator(10); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Si sé que es lo correcto implementarlas pero, ¿El compilador de C# se da cuenta de cuando quiero volver una clase iterable con `foreach`?

Comment: claro, eso es justamente lo que comento, y lo que menciona el link, .net puede determinar por los metodos que expone que es una clase que puede iterarse, por eso no es necesario implementarla de forma completa